# firebase auth losing cookies on refresh

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

**Technologies**: Framework: **Angular**, Components: **Ionic**, Auth-Service: **Firebase**, NPM-Module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/fire

**Situation**:
The user can login by username and password or by using Google Auth. When the user is logged in, then some cookies are stored in the browser.

As requested here is the code I use to log in:

**Login**

```
loginWithGoogle() {
    from(this.authService.logIn())
        .pipe(
            concatMap(() => this.authService.getAuth().signInWithPopup(new auth.GoogleAuthProvider())),
            concatMap(userCredential => this.initStateAndRoute(userCredential)),
        )
        .subscribe();
}
```

**AuthService**

```
export class AuthService {

constructor(
    private fireAuth: AngularFireAuth,
) {
}

getUser(): Observable<firebase.User> {
    return this.fireAuth.user;
}

logOut() {
    return this.fireAuth.auth.signOut();
}

getAuth() {
    return this.fireAuth.auth;
}

logIn() {
    return this.fireAuth.auth.setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL);
}
```

}

**Auth-Guard-Service**

```
@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {
constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router,
) {
}

canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {

    if (this.authService.getAuth().currentUser) {
        return true;
    }

    this.router.navigateByUrl('login');
    return false;
}
```

**Problem**: When the website gets refreshed, then all those cookies are lost and the user is automatically logged out.

I want the users to stay logged in even when they refresh the site. What am I missing?

Comment: Firebase Auth does retain the currently logged in user between page refreshes.  You might be doing something wrong.  Please edit the question to show the code that's not working the way you expect.  You should be using an auth state listener to pick up the authenticated user when that information is available.

Comment: Marking down question because you do not provide your login in code. Might be your Authentication State Persistence, try setting to local https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence

Comment: I updated and added the code. Still not working so far...

Comment: @BrianOgden As mentioned in the doc the default should be firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL. This means the user should be still logged in after a refresh. So the problem should be somewhere else...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your problem is that the guard directing user to login page even though they are logged in after refresh, then I recommend using AngularFireAuthGuard instead of a regular Angular guard.

You can basically implement this into your app-routing.module and it handles everything for you. Also, with using this you don't need the Auth-Guard-Service anymore.

A very simple example:

into app.module:

```
import { AngularFireAuthGuardModule } from '@angular/fire/auth-guard'; 

@NgModule({
   declarations: [],
   imports: [
      AngularFireAuthGuardModule,
   ],
   providers: [],
   bootstrap: []
})
```

and into app-routing.module:

```
import { AngularFireAuthGuard, redirectUnauthorizedTo, redirectLoggedInTo } from '@angular/fire/auth-guard';

const redirectUnauthorizedToHome = () => redirectUnauthorizedTo(['home']);
const redirectLoggedInToAccount = () => redirectLoggedInTo(['my-account']);

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'my-account', component: MyAccountComponent, canActivate: [AngularFireAuthGuard], data: { authGuardPipe: redirectUnauthorizedToHome } },
  { path: 'create-account', component: CreateAccountComponent, canActivate: [AngularFireAuthGuard], data: { authGuardPipe: redirectLoggedInToAccount } },
];
```

You can look at the details from here: https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/auth/router-guards.md

Comment: Indeed... Using this AngularFireAuthGuardModule solved my problem. Thx! :)